# tomcat trying to connect socket failed

Tags: apache, sockets, tomcat

I am stuck in trying to connect tomcat 5.5.36 with apache 2.4 using AJP 1.3 protocol and mod_jk 1.2.40

```
[Mon Apr 13 18:46:39 2015][4680:5612] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c
(593): socket TCP_NODELAY set to On
[Mon Apr 13 18:46:39 2015][4680:5612] [debug] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (717): trying to connect socket 1184 to 0.0.0.0:8009
[Mon Apr 13 18:46:39 2015][4680:5612] [info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (735): connect to 0.0.0.0:8009 failed (errno=49)
[Mon Apr 13 18:46:39 2015][4680:5612] [info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1019): Failed opening socket to (0.0.0.0:8009) (errno=49)
[Mon Apr 13 18:46:39 2015][4680:5612] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1659): (worker1) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=49)
[Mon Apr 13 18:46:39 2015][4680:5612] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2669): (worker1) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=1)
[Mon Apr 13 18:46:39 2015][4680:5612] [debug] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2518): retry 1, sleeping for 100 ms before retrying
[Mon Apr 13 18:46:39 2015][4680:5612] [debug] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1653): (worker1) all endpoints are disconnected.
```

**server.xml**

```
<Connector port="8009" 
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" />
```

**httpd.conf**

```
# Where to find workers.properties
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
# Where to put jk shared memory -> apache log
JkShmFile logs/mod_jk.shm
# Log directory of the mod
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
# Set the jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel debug
# Select the timestamp log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]"
#JkOptions DisableReuse, you ask mod_jk to close connections immediately after their use.
#Normally mod_jk uses persistent connections and pools idle 
#connections to reuse them, when new requests have to be sent to Tomcat. 
JkOptions     +DisableReuse
```

**workers.properties**

```
worker.list=worker1

#Set properties for worker1 (ajp13) 
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
```

**virtual host**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/docs"
    ServerName dummy-host
    ServerAlias 192.168.92.195 localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common

    JkMount /webportal/* worker1
    JkMount /webportal   worker1


</VirtualHost>
```

i feel like there is problem with mod_jk so i tried different binaries but no success thanks in advance

Comment: I agree with the error message. Tomcat is probably not started.

Comment: it is working properly on localhost:8080 port its mean tom cat is started